# Unique key setup ignoring a specific duplicate value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an MVC code running which required a setup where an No two same Employeeid's can remain active.

Requirement Explanation >> Duplicate EmployeeID's can not stay active at the same time ,but if you delete the employeeid then multiple deleted entries can remain there. i.e

EmployeeID |   IsDeleted

```
1         |      1         >   ok
1         |      0         >   ok
1         |      0         >   Not Allowed.
1         |      1         >   It should be allowed but here the constraint throws error.
```

Please note in the application scenario, i am not running an insert with the 'isdeleted' = 1 flag but i am just deleting the active record and updating the value of 'isDeleted' from 0 to 1.

Steps Taken >> i tried making a unique constraint in database on combination of (EmployeeID , IsDeleted) but as explained above it throws error when i am trying to update the 'isDeleted' flag from 0 to 1, (reason - there is already an entry with same EmployeeID and Isdeleted as 1).

Outcome to accomplish >> 'IsDeleted' should be successfully updated from 0 to 1.

Outcome recieved by now >> Update failed due to unique constraint.

Pls help !

Comment: Why are there multiple entries for EmployeeID = 1?

Comment: @marcos, because you can delete an employee and can create again with the same Employee ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index unq_t_employeeId_isdeleted_0 on t(employeeId)
   where isDeleted = 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57a66af6fd7c8033996a1c10b58d706e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: but that does not throw exception when i insert a record with duplicate Employeeid and isdeleted =0  (when there is already a record with same employeeid and isdeleted=0)

Comment: @isha . . . That needs to be a **unique** index.  I stated it in the text but left out the keyword in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your unique constraint will not work because the only allowed values are (EmployeeId, 0) and (EmployeeId, 1), with no duplicates.

To solve your problem, you can create a `FUNCTION` and use it with `CHECK`.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION CountActive(
    @EmployeeId INT
)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN  (
        SELECT  COUNT(1)
        FROM    [dbo].[Employee]
        WHERE [EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId
            AND [IsDeleted] = 0
    );
END;
```

And, on your table add a `CHECK` constraint:

```
CHECK([CountActive]([EmployeeId]) <= 1)
```

It allows at most one active `EmployeeId`.